# Taskbar hiding behind maximized window in Windows 10 Dual Monitor

Tags: windows-10, multiple-monitors, taskbar

i'm using windows 10 with a dual monitor setup

after some random time using the computer the taskbar (which is set to auto-hide) will keep hidden behind any maximized window and won't pop up when the mouse is hovered over the edge of the screen.

the only way of making it appear is to press the windows key, which will make the taskbar show up with the start menu.

when the taskbar is visible, if i click an empty space in it the problem is solved for a while, but it will happen again in a short time

i tried both putting the taskbar at the botton or the top with no change

i'm not using "full screen mode" (F11)

i've also updated display drivers with no luck